# Module build failed @content($material-light) vuetify 2.3.10

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, yarnpkg, package.json

I am upgrading from vuetify version 1.0.5 to 2.3.10. I have removed node-sass and using sass as per the documentation. I am getting this error as below. I have included my package.json file. Any idea where I could be wrong?

```
./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass
Module build failed: 
    @content($material-light)
   ^
      Invalid CSS after "    @content": expected "}", was "($material-light); "
      in /Users/weather/ceolaw/node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/tools/_theme.sass (line 3, column 5)
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass 2:14-102
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/es5/presets/default/index.js
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "weather",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.21.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.0",
    "@riophae/vue-treeselect": "^0.0.38",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.0.550",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "scroll-into-view-if-needed": "^2.2.14",
    "urijs": "^1.19.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-ads-table-tree": "^2.3.2",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.9.0",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.6.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.10",
    "yarn": "^1.22.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000855",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.6.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client": "./bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "server": "bundle exec rails s",
    "start": "./bin/webpack-dev-server"
  }
}
```

Error update

```
yarn remove node-sass

yarn remove v1.21.1
[1/2]   Removing module node-sass...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
```

Comment: Did you deleted `node-sass` from `node_modules` ? Because you get this exact error when using Vuetify 2.x with `node-sass` - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7323

Comment: @MichalLevý I just checked my node-modules folder and I was able to find node-sass there. But my package.json file does have node-sass then why does my node-modules has node-sass?

Comment: Maybe because you edited your `package.json` by hand instead of executing `yarn remove node-sass`

Comment: @MichalLevý I tried removing it using yarn remove node-sass 
This is what the output I am getting.
yarn remove v1.21.1
[1/2]   Removing module node-sass...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.

 Any idea how I can solve this?
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.

Comment: @MichalLevý please check error update in the question just to have a better clarity of the previous comment.

Comment: No need to do it now if you already removed it by editing `package.json`. Just delete the directory from `node_modules`

Comment: @MichalLevý I deleted the node-sass directory from node-modules and it works but the issue is when I delete the node-modules directory and do yarn install the node-sass comes back

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of your other dependencies has a dependency on `node-sass`. It's probably `@rails/webpacker` as you are using very old version 3.2.0 (current is [5.2.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rails/webpacker)) and they switched to `sass` (`dart-sass`) [recently](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/commit/950979a2ee7e1ebc819ce226184637c4cfc685bd)

Result is you have both packages installed - `sass` and `node-sass`

From the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#implementation) of `sass-loader` (which is used by Webpack when building Vue app) it seems that when both packages are installed, they prefer `sass` over `node-sass` but at the same time warn not to install both. Seems strange to me. Also the error suggests that `sass-loader` is in your case preferring `node-sass`.

You have 2 options:

1. upgrade `@rails/webpacker` to newer version which is using `sass`
2. configure `sass-loader` to use `sass` as documented [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#implementation)